# SSH login with Key not working

Tags: ssh, password

I followed a guide for password-less login:

```
# Generate Key
ssh-keygen

#Append Key
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@remotehost 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'

#login
ssh user@remotehost.com
```

... I opened authorized_keys to make sure the key was added, but I still have to enter password to login.

I even tried copying with `ssh-copy-id` and the keys get added successfully, but still it asks for password.

```
myname-MBP:~ mynameezzy$ ssh myname@host.net "ls -la .ssh"
myname@host.net's password: 
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 myname neouser 4096 Sep 14 09:58 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 myname myname 4096 Sep 14 12:02 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname neouser  811 Sep 15 01:38 authorized_keys
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname neouser  400 Sep 12 02:32 authorized_keys.bak
-rw------- 1 myname neouser 1675 Sep 11 11:27 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myname neouser  400 Sep 11 11:27 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 myname neouser 1010 Sep 14 09:58 known_hosts
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the server's logs to find out what went wrong.

Comment: And edit into your question the output of `ssh user@remotehost "ls -la .ssh"`.

Comment: @MadHatter added output

Comment: @MichaelHampton I checked in ~/logs and /logs, didn't find anything.

Comment: Nimbuz, the etiquette around these parts is that when you're satisfied with an answer to your question, you accept it by clicking the tick outline next to it.  This drives the SF reputation system both for you and the author of the accepted answer.  I apologise if you already know this, but you have several older SF questions with valid answers, none of which have been accepted; you might want to go back and review those.

Comment: Thats because none of the answers are satisfactory, but I've accepted them anyway.

Comment: For questions that old, that's best-practice.  You can always unaccept one of those, and accept a better, should it come along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `remotehost`, try

```
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Edit**: I find the fast way to sort out most of these problems is to run a second, non-detaching, logging `sshd` on another port on the remote server, and connect to that.

On server: `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222`

On client: `ssh remotehost -p 2222`

Then look closely at STDOUT from the non-detaching sshd.  You may need to open up an inbound port on `remotehost`'s firewall; in this case, 2222.

Comment: Thanks, but still asks for password :(

Answer (score 1):

Change permission for your .ssh directory

```
  chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh
  chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: You don't want to make that recursive.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is fairly simple, so assuming you haven't made any config changes, there isn't a whole lot to troubleshoot.

Are you able to use your client to log in with SSH and public key to any machine at all?

Visually verify that the public key on the host machine matches the public key on the client. Seems dumb, I know, but I've messed this up before. I usually just do a quick check that the first and last ~20 characters match and there are no spaces.

Verify that on the host machine `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf` has the following:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Make the group of `.ssh/` directory and its contents the same group as the user on both machines.

```
chown username:username -R ~/.ssh/
```

Try logging in by requiring key use

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub username@servername
```